# am i using while wrong (PYTHON)

Tags: python, loops, while-loop, gr

I'm trying to get the user to input the right name, but when I run it keeps asking me to rewrite even when I entered jayson tatum, but when I wrote lebron james it works? Thanks for your inspections
Here's the code

```
while favPlayer != 'lebron james' and 'jayson tatum':

    favPlayer = str.lower(input('Favorite player on the list (Lebron James, Jayson Tatum): '))

if favPlayer == 'jayson tatum':

    position = 'Small Forward'

    print('Your position is Small Forward')

elif favPlayer == 'lebron james':

    position = 'Power Forward'

    print('Your position is Power Forward')
```

Here's the run:
[enter image description here][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9bem2.png

Comment: Probably `while favPlayer != 'lebron james' and favPlayer != 'jayson tatum':`.

Comment: Alternatively: `while favPlayer not in ['lebron james', 'jayson tatum']:`.

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is in your `and` in your `while` condition.

```
while favPlayer != 'lebron james' and 'jayson tatum':
```

`and` is used to to test two conditions, but here it's testing a condition (`favPlayer != 'lebron james`) and a string (`'jayson tatum'`).

Instead

```
while favPlayer != 'lebron james' and favPlayer != 'jayson tatum':
```

---

The reason your attempt ran without error is that any non-zero thing in python is considered `True`. So really your while statement was being interpreted as:

```
 while favPlayer != 'lebron james' and True:
```

Which is the same as

```
 while favPlayer != 'lebron james':
```

Answer (score -1):

You can take input using an infinite while loop until the user enters one of the names:

```
while True:
    favPlayer = str.lower(
        input('Favorite player on the list (Lebron James, Jayson Tatum): '))
    if favPlayer == 'jayson tatum':
        position = 'Small Forward'
        print('Your position is Small Forward')
        break
    elif favPlayer == 'lebron james':
        position = 'Power Forward'
        print('Your position is Power Forward')
        break
```

Output:

```
Favorite player on the list (Lebron James, Jayson Tatum): Arsho
Favorite player on the list (Lebron James, Jayson Tatum): Lebron James
Your position is Power Forward
```

Comment: I really don't understand why `while True:` would be preferable to putting the condition that causes `break` in the `while` itself. I know it's likely a matter of opinion, but every time I see `while True:` in real life code, I know I'm going on a wild goose chase to find all the `break` lines. Maybe there is more to it since this seems to be more common in python than other languages.

Comment: Don't indent the if-elif block: the while loop *only* checks for valid input; the result of the user entry is handled outside of the while loop.

Comment: This is not a production-level code. This kind of exercise typically requires a lot of `if`, `else-if` and using breaks gives some kind of feel of `switch` block. Assume, there are more than 5 names. It would be really hard to maintain this condition in the `while name!="name_1" or name!="name_2" ...`

Comment: `while name not in valid_names:` would be perfectly fine in that case.

Comment: @9769953 good catch on the list. I did not want to introduce the list concept assuming OP is practicing loop and conditional statements only.

Comment: That is often hard to tell; it may be practice, it may be learning Python without any specific language practices. I guess that's why I automatically commented the correct comparison, and the more Python-esque comparison for this case.